# Using UiAutomator to test if map has loaded or not

Tags: android, maps, android-testing, android-uiautomator, android-espresso

I am new to testing in android. I have a map activity, which is called after some events in the MainActivity and a map appears in the screen. I am not able to figure out how to test whether the map appears or not.
I understand its not possible with espresso, but have read somewhere that its possible with UiAutomator. How to use UiAutomator for the same..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the content description of the View hosting the map to indicate its "readiness".

```
    ...
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapView = mapFragment.getView();
    mapView.setContentDescription("MAP NOT READY");
    // you may need to preserve existing description
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    ...
    mapView.setContentDescription("MAP READY");
 }
```

Then, on your test

```
mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.desc("MAP READY")), timeout);
```

Comment: Getting ClassCastException :FrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap for the line: googleMap = mapFragment.getView();  ?

Comment: This helps for me to fix :)

Answer (score 0):

**This solution worked for me:** I have just updated @Diego's solution because, I got the `ClassCastException` on this line `mapView = mapFragment.getView();`  So I have removed this line and not setting the content description on initial, because googleMap by default have a content description as "Google Map" so no need to set it just update it inside:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    ...
    mapView.setContentDescription("Google Map Ready");
 }
```

then wait in your test class like:

```
mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.desc("Google Map Ready")), timeout);
```